# Model hierarchy in Django

Tags: python, sql, django, orm

Sorry for the long text

Models are given:

1. User
2. Hierarchy

   class Hierarchy (Model):

   ```
     owner = OneToOneField(User)
     subordinates = ManyToManyField(User)
   ```

There are users, they can invite each other. The invitees, in turn, can accept the invite or reject it.

Suppose that Mark invited Masha, Katya and Dima. Masha accepted Mark's invitation, and even invited Kolya herself.

On one tab, you need to display the hierarchy.

Continuing the example, Mark should have:

```
1st level: Masha, Katya, Dima
2nd level: Kolya and other guys

1st level for Mark - those whom he invited.
2nd level - those who were invited by people invited by Mark.
```

And so on.

Tell me how to implement it | what to familiarize yourself with to get closer to the result

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free coding site. Please demonstrate reasonable effort by implementing it yourself first, and, if stumbled, publish a specific problem to get further assistance once your initial implementation, however problematic, is in place.

Comment: I always try it myself first, and only then ask for help. The best attempt was this:



main_hier = Hierarchy.objects.filter(pk=id). values_list('subordinates', flat=True)
level_hier = {}

for sub in main_hier:
    try:
        hier = Hierarchy.objects.filter(pk=id). values_list('subordinates')
    except Hierarchy.DoesNotExist:
        hier = {}

    level_hier[sub] = hier
return level_hier

Comment: @H-Machine, can you please post your code in the question section instead of the comments section. That way we can review your code and provide some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want a tree, not a graph. In such cases To minimize database queries you need to modernize your hierarchy model

- [Install django-mptt](https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html)
- change model

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey

class Hierarchy(MPTTModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    owner = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='subordinates')

    class MPTTMeta:
        parent_attr = 'owner'
        level_attr = 'mptt_level'
        order_insertion_by=['user']
```

- Get your list

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from .models import Hierarchy
# Get owner
owner = get_object_or_404(Hierarchy, pk=owner_id)
# Get tree users from database
users = Hierarchy.objects.filter(tree_id=owner.tree_id, level__gt=owner.level).select_related('user').order_by('level')

# serialize tree
users_list = []           # list levels users  with users   
users_on_level = []       # list of users of the current tree level
tree_level = owner.level  # current tree level

for user in users:
    if user.level > tree_level:
        tree_level += 1
        users_list.append(users_on_level)
        users_on_level = []
    users_on_level.append(user)

# output users
for level, users in enumerate(users_list, 1):
    print(f"{level} - {', '.join(str(user.username) for user in users) }"
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, I hope it helps someone else. I didn’t use your solution, but it got me thinking and I came up with my own. This might not have happened if it weren't for you.

Comment: I wanted to mark the answer as helpful, but I don't have enough reputation / points